# How to make Firefox button looks like Chrome button (border, border-radius, padding, margin..)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

**firefox:** [image] **google-chrome:**[image]

```
.stdbutton{
    width:100px;
    height: 20px;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
         padding: 0 !important;
         border: 0 none !important;

     }
```

How to make them look the same? `border-radius:0px;` has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each browser renders `<button>` differently. There is no single CSS property which standardizes the visual appearance of buttons throughout all browsers.

If you want a standardized appearance, either use a JS plugin to accomplish that, or remove the default browser styling by setting

`-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;`

on the button, and then style it according to how you want it to appear.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this on your buttons:

```
-webkit-appearance:     none;
-moz-appearance:        none;
-ms-appearance:         none;
-o-appearance:          none;
appearance:             none;
```

And then style them together equally

Comment: That is not how vendor prefixes work. You don't just slap all the prefixes to all the properties.